# How do I create one instance of setinterval where I can change the timing?

Tags: jquery

```
$(function() {
    setInterval( function(){clickRight();}, 5000 );
});
```

I have this function that executes on load for a slider. However when I add another setInterval for when someone clicks the next button it doesnt reset the setinterval but creates another timer.

How do I reset the main timer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove an interval with the clearInterval() function:

```
var myInterval = setInterval( function(){clickRight();}, 5000 );
....
clearInterval(myInterval);
```

Comment: if I click the next button and I reset timer right away it seems to just make another setinterval

Comment: nm I was var timer= when it should be timer =

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reset the timer. Instead you will have to clear the timer and set it again. To do this you simply need to set you timer to a variable:

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){ /* some code */ }, 10000);
```

Then when you want to clear it use

```
clearInterval(timer);
```

Answer (score 1):

that, you cannot.

but you can do it with a recursive called setTimeout/setInterval.

something like:

```
var t, f, i = 100, s = 0;

f = function () {

  s++;
  if(s> 100){
     s = 0;
     clearInterval(t)
     i+= 100 //<<--- 
     t = setInterval(f,i); // <-- yes a new Timer is created
  }
}

t = setInterval(f,i);
```